# Higher Deploy Cost on Matching Contracts

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, gas, etherscan, ganache

Recently I found any verified contract source code that I copy from Etherscan and deployed on my Ganache testnet is approximately **double the cost, and gas used,** from the contract's real deployment on the mainnet.

For testing purposes I'm copying the source code from [AzuKID DAO](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7581f90f03f1f3ed8dc1755caecb4fd2495c48c6) and deploying on my Ganache v2.5.4 testnet. I've copied the source code directly from Etherscan and tried to mimic the compiler settings as well.

I copied the average network gas price from the [Contract Creation TxN](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7581f90f03f1f3ed8dc1755caecb4fd2495c48c6) to my truffle configuration.

My `truffle.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
      development: {
          gasPrice: 145336353833,
          host: "127.0.0.1",
          port: 7545,
          network_id: "*" // Match any network id
      }
  },
  contracts_directory: './src/contracts/',
  contracts_build_directory: './src/abis/',
  migrations_directory: "./src/migrations/",
  compilers: {
      solc: {
          version: "0.8.10",
          optimizer: {
              enabled: true,
              runs: 1000
          },
          "outputSelection": {
            "*": {
              "*": [
                "evm.bytecode",
                "evm.deployedBytecode",
                "devdoc",
                "userdoc",
                "metadata",
                "abi"
              ]
            }
          },
          "libraries": {}
      }
  }
}
```

My Result:

```
Gas Used: 5359166
Gas Price: 145.336353833 gwei
Total Cost: 0.77889094755242859 ETH
```

Their Result:

```
Gas Used: 2443942
Gas Price: 145.336353833 Gwei
Total Cost: 0.355193619259329686 ETH
```

**What am I doing wrong here?**

**Is this an issue with Truffle or am I not understanding gas properly?**

Comment: Are you deploying exactly the same contracts? What do the migrations scripts look like?

Comment: I'm deploying the same solidity files, but I don't know the details of their migration scripts. 

My latest guess is that one of their dependency contracts is stored separately on the blockchain and they are referencing the address in their migrations. I guess Etherscan wouldn't show this in the verified code portion?

Comment: Etherscan show only the parameters for one deployed contract. There are several contracts but only one bytecode is generated from them. You could look at the deployer account and check if other contracts are deployed.